Why does console log undefined when fetching data from Strapi API in Next.js?
I'm trying to fetch posts from my Strapi backend in a Next.js application. My Strapi server is running on localhost:1337. Here is my component code:
When I try to fetch data, posts is logged as undefined
I have confirmed that NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL is correctly set to http://localhost:1337 in my .env file.
import React from "react";
import Post from "./Post";

const RecentPosts = ({ posts }) => {
  console.log(posts); // Logs 'undefined'

  return (
    <div className="mx-auto flex h-full w-full max-w-7xl flex-col gap-12 p-4 md:p-8">
      <div className="rounded-lg bg-backgroundSecondary p-4">
        <h2 className="text-balance text-center text-3xl font-semibold uppercase text-[#f2f2f2] md:text-left md:text-4xl lg:text-5xl xl:text-6xl">
          Ostatnie wpisy
        </h2>
        <p className="text-center text-lg md:text-left">
          Zobacz kilka z naszych ostatnich wpisów i dowiedz się więcej na temat
          Arbosfery!
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-6 xl:flex-row">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

RecentPosts.getInitialProps = async () => {
  try {
    const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;
    const res = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/posts?_sort=createdAt:desc`);
    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }
    const posts = await res.json();
    return { posts };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
    return { posts: [] };
  }
};

export default RecentPosts;

Why is posts undefined when it should contain the fetched data from the API?

Your apiUrl is missing the /api endpoint. API endpoints are prefixed with /api by default. It should be:
http://localhost:1337/**api**/posts... 

unless you changed this in the settings.
Here is the image from the Strapi docs:

